# Sort a list in haskell according to a predicate

Tags: sorting, haskell

I am trying to learn Haskell and I've come into issues trying to complete an example problem. The problem is to sort a list in Haskell according to a given predicate i.e. the type is

```
sort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The code I have so far is :

```
sort _ [] = []
sort f (x:xs) =
            let 
            smaller = sort f (filter (f x) xs)
            bigger = sort f (filter (f x) xs) --error is on this line 
            in smaller ++ [x] ++ bigger
```

The code not working correctly in the sense im not sure how to take the opposite of the function. for example if it were an ordinary sort function I would use `smaller = quicksort (filter (<=x) xs)` and `bigger = quicksort (filter (>x) xs)` this would then break up the list according to that predicate but how do I do this with a higher order predicate?

Comment: First of all, you need to indent `smaller` and `bigger` over so that they're passed the `let`.  Second, You might want to look at the `not` function.

Comment: @bheklilr Seems to compile fine for me like this. Should the `not` function be used like `(not f x)`? because this gives me compiler errors.

Comment: Try `(not (f x))` or `(not $ f x)`, `f` isn't an argument to `not`, `f x` is the argument you want to give to it.

Comment: neither of those appear to work

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have been `not . f x`, since `f` is a function of two arguments.  The above syntax would have worked with a lambda function like `filter (\y -> not $ f x y) xs`.  My mistake.

Comment: oh perfect thanks. If you want the rep add that as an answer.

Comment: You might like to use [partition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `not` function to invert your boolean:

```
not :: Bool -> Bool

f :: a -> a -> Bool
f x :: a -> Bool

not . f x :: a -> Bool
```

And you'd use it as

```
sort _ [] = []
sort f (x:xs) =
    let smaller = sort f (filter (f x) xs)
        bigger  = sort f (filter (not . f x) xs)
    in smaller ++ [x] ++ bigger
```